# Как создать звуковой файл?

Tags: php, звукозапись

В идеале все так: пользователь на сайте жмет на кнопку, что-то говорит, жмет на стоп, и на сервере появляется звуковой файл с его речью. Реализуемо ли это на php? Если нет, то как это сделать?

Comment: Вот много полезного по данной теме [http://habrahabr.ru/qa/3811/](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/3811/)

Answer (score 1):

С помощью Flash(ActionScript). На PHP можно лишь обрабатывать аудио файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку PHP отвечает за серверную часть, то сделать запись средствами одного PHP не получится, потребуется нечто, что будет выполнять звукозапись на клиенте. Вариантов для клиента достаточно: это Java-апплеты, Silverlight-приложения и Flash-приложения. Собственно сама звукозапись во всех случаях выполняется просто, сложности могут возникнуть при отправке записанного файла на сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать с помощью *WebRTC*, это *JS* библиотека. Документация [здесь](http://recordrtc.org/).

Вот [демо](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/).